Django template for RTL
I have this in one of my Django 5.0 templates:
{% load i18n %}
<div class="pt-2 text-center">
 {% translate 'Already have an account?' %}
 <a class=" text-decoration-none" href="{% url 'myapp:sign_in' %}">{% translate 'Sign in' %}</a>
</div>

How do I rewrite this so that it is compatible with RTL languages in the future?
Edit: Currently using Bootstrap 5.3.3.
